# VBA code to fetch data from Mysql DB in Mac Excel 2011

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I was using ADODB code in Windows to fetch data from Mysql Database and it was working fine. However, I can not seem to get my Excel workbook (using ADODB) to work with Excel Mac 2011.  After a lot of googling, I found an ODBC connector from Actual tech and I was able to fetch  three rows using Microsoft Query. But I want this to be done using VBA code but have been unable to do so. Has anyone gotten this to work? If yes, can you please provide me with a sample code. Thanks in Advance !!

P.S: I know there is a similar existing question but the link provided in the answer is no longer working. hence, I have asked a new question

Also, If anyone needs the link to do it through Microsoft Query, here is the link:
http://www.agentjim.com/MVP/Excel/2011Relational7Queries.html

Here is the code I use in Windows:

```
  Sub getMysqlDBdata()

  Dim Cn As Object
  Dim sqlQa as string
  dim temparray1 as variant

  Source = "MySQL"

  mysql_driver = "MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver"

  sqlQa = "select * from test.TestTable;"

  Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Cn.Open "Driver={" & "MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver" & "};Server=" & "127.0.01" & ";Database= test;UID=" & "root" & ";PWD=" & "12345"

  rs.Open sqlQa, Cn, adOpenStatic
  temparray1 = rs.GetRows()
  rs.Close

  Set rs = Nothing



  End Sub
```

Comment: Any pointers on where to start in Mac Excel 2011. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of googling I came across this sample code provided by [Bryan Duchesne](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/e5417259-c3c9-4d46-a75f-ac1e2b602a33) in MSDN:

```
Sub TestSqlConnection()
Dim sqlstring As String
Dim connstring As String
Dim sLogin As String
sLogon = "Uid=myUserID;Pwd=myPassowrkd;"
sqlstring = "select * from zitemloc"
connstring = "ODBC;DSN=myDSN;" & sLogon
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:t2000").Clear

Dim qt As QueryTable
For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
    qt.Delete
Next qt
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("B1"),   Sql:=sqlstring)
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With

Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)
Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = UBound(qt.ResultRange.Value)


Dim ix, iy As Integer
Dim data As Variant
Dim colCount As Integer
colCount = qt.ResultRange.Columns.Count

For ix = 1 To rowCount
    If Not IsArray(data) Then
            ReDim data(rowCount - 1, colCount - 1)
    End If
    For iy = 1 To qt.ResultRange.Columns.Count
        data(ix - 1, iy - 1) = qt.ResultRange.Value2(ix, iy)

    Next
Next
End Sub
```