# Connect to sql server with ActualTech odbc Driver - VBA Office 2011 on Mac

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, macos

I'm working on Mac OS X Yosemite with MS Office 2011. I'm trying to connect my Excel Workbook to a sql-database. This has to be done through VBA as later I want to read as well as write data to the database.

I couldn't find a way to establish a connection to that database. I downloaded the actualtech odbc driver and setup my dsn (not sure if I did it right though, couldn't find how to do it with a sql-server on a homepage).

The following code is all I could find. I get errors:

```
strSRV = "server_name"
strDB = "database_name"
sqlLogin = "TEST" 'has to be changed
sqlPW = "TEST_PW" 'has to be changed

strConn = "ODBC;DSN=" & strSRV & ";UID=" & sqlLogin & ";PWD=" & sqlPW & ";Database=gi_kunden"
                   
With Sheets("Firma").ListObjects
    sqlCommand = "Select * From tbl_firma"
    .Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=strConn, LinkSource:=True, Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Firma").Range("A2")).QueryTable 'Get an error here
    .CommandText = Array(sqlCommand)
End With

With Sheets("Person").ListObjects
    sqlCommand = "Select * From tbl_person"
    .Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=strConn, LinkSource:=True, Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person").Range("A2")).QueryTable 'Get an error here
    .CommandText = Array(sqlCommand)
End With
```

Also tried the following code:

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;" & _
          "Server=" & strSRV & ";" & _
          "Database=" & strDB & ";" & _
          "UID=" & sqlLogin & ";" & _
          "PWD=" & sqlPW & ";"
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument :(

Comment: also odbc.connection and odbc.recordset do not work...

Comment: I also changed strSRV="gi_kunden" as in the odbc manager....

Comment: Hi there: I found a reason why it didn't work in the first place... the ODBC driver that I had downloaded, didn't include the drivers. So although they were shown in the ODBC-manager they have never been installed. Now I can at least almost make a connection to the server. Seems though that I need to add a new user to the SQL database which is allowed to connect from elsewhere... I'll update this thread if I should get it working... Still if someone has some tipps, i'll appreciate them :) Thanks for now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it working......... :)

I changed the code from [VBA code to fetch data from Mysql DB in Mac Excel 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433645/vba-code-to-fetch-data-from-mysql-db-in-mac-excel-2011?rq=1) and adapted it to the following:

```
Sub SqlConnection()
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim sLogin As String
    sLogin = "Uid=$;Pwd=$;"
    sqlstringfirma = "select * from gi_kunden.tbl_firma"
    sqlstringperson = "select * from gi_kunden.tbl_person"
    connstring = "ODBC;DSN=KundeDB;" & sLogin

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Firma").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T2000").Clear

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstringfirma)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T2000").Clear

    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstringperson)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

This works fine it seems.... After hours and hours of surfing and googling ^^ (halleluja!!)

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this code, be aware that for your database you have to declare which table in your database should be selected. For me this was gi_kunden.tbl_firma so database.table. Else there is a high possibility of no return of data from the database ;) CU

Comment: But, this is a read-only link, isn't it?  You said you needed to do writes also, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do.  Did you find a solution for writing to your sql server from VBA code on the Mac?

Comment: @DanielSkarbek I gave up on this project as soon as Office was updated and they added their own odbc driver, which I couldn't configure. As I haven't worked with this for a while now, I can't really help you anymore, but if you'll ask the question with your specific problem, I'm sure someone will be helping you.

Comment: This works very well and elegantly. I used to use the ADODB connection but couldn't get it working when I switched to a Mac. One minor edit, "sLogon" should be "sLogin".

Comment: @SteveGon I've had quite some problems working with vba on mac. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057385/refresh-querytable-throwing-general-odbc-error-vba-excel-2011-for-mac . This is a follow-up question after this one. After the update that I related to in that post, I gave up on this project. But it may help you find a solution to get yours working. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a little more information. I managed to get the data through odbc from the sql-database manually and this is the code I got from recording it:

```
Sub GetFromSQL()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ID]]" _
    ))
        .PostText = "ExternalData_1"
        .Name = True
        .FieldNames = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .HasAutoFormat = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = 1
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Problem is, I'm not able to re-run this macro as the part where I connect to the database as well as the query are nowhere to be found here.

Does anyone have a clue, what I need to add to this code, so it'll work?

Thankx for your support.

CU Kath