# Refresh QueryTable throwing "General ODBC error" - VBA Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

***EDIT: New mistake found?***

I may have just found out why my script wouldn't work anymore. There has been an office update recently and it seems they have implemented the microsoft query which gets rid of the ODBC-Manager which I installed and configured to my needs. Now the actual problem may be that this microsoft query doesn't have the UNICODE-library and I don't know where I could put them so that the microsoft query would read/get them. Or rather I don't know how to give the microsoft query the path to the UNICODE-library as in the manager there is no possibility to change it, or maybe there is and I just didn't find it? In addition to this I cannot open the microsoft query manager unless I open it directly from the excel workbook.

***ORIGINAL QUESTION***

This code worked for some time. Now with the exact same code I get a runtime error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998229/vba-mac-connect-to-sql-server-with-actualtech-odbc-driver) I already asked for help in this case and got it to work.

Here's the code:

```
Sub ConnectSQL()

    Dim connstring As String
    Dim sLogin As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    sLogin = "Uid=*;Pwd=*;"
    sqlstringFirma = "select * from gi_kunden.tbl_Firma"
    sqlstringPerson = "select * from gi_kunden.tbl_Person"
    connstring = "ODBC;DSN=KundeDB;" & sLogin

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Firma").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T2000").Clear

    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstringFirma)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh '"General ODBC error" hereeee
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T2000").Clear

    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstringPerson)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh 'And hereee again
    End With


    Call Replace
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Firma").Select

End Sub
```

I did use .Select twice here and I know I should change it.

I am working in Excel 2011 on a Mac so be aware that not everything that works on windows will work.

*** EDIT ***

First of all: Even if I have all the object libraries activated, this still doesn't work.

Secondly, I just realized some things as I opened the Object Browser:

1. "ODBCConnection" is a declared class ("Class ODBCConnection Member of Excel"). But when I click on Excel in the Object-Browser "ODBCConnection" is nowhere to be found. If I enter the code "Excel.ODBCConnection.Refresh" it throws the error "Method or Data Member not found" highlighting only the word "ODBCConnection". Same error is shown when I use only ODBCConnection.Refresh (Refresh being a method of ODBCConnection according to the Object Browser).
2. I have exactly the same problem with "QueryTable(1).Refresh", which is throwing the error: "Variable not defined" even though it's listed and declared in the object-browser ("Class QueryTable Member of Excel").

I believe I would get these kind of errors for all the things that are connected to this.

***EDIT***

This throws the same "General ODBC error" on the line ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll:

```
Dim strConn As String
Dim strLoginData As String
Dim QT As QueryTable

Dim strFirmSQL As String
Dim strPersSQL As String

strConn = "ODBC;DSN=KundeDB;" & strLoginData
strLoginData = "Uid=*myUid*;Pwd=*myPwd*"

strFirmSQL = "Select * From gi_kunden.tbl_firma"
strPersSQL = "Select * From gi_kunden.tbl_person"

Dim WSFirm As Worksheet
Set WSFirm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Firma")

WSFirm.Range("A1:T1000").Clear

For Each QT In WSFirm.QueryTables
    QT.Delete
Next QT

With WSFirm.QueryTables.Add(strConn, WSFirm.Range("A1"), strFirmSQL)
    .SaveData = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    '.Refresh
End With


Dim WSPers As Worksheet
Set WSPers = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person")

For Each QT In WSPers.QueryTables
    QT.Delete
Next QT

With WSPers.QueryTables.Add(strConn, WSPers.Range("A1"), strPersSQL)
    .SaveData = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    '.Refresh
End With

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'FAILS here

Call Replace

WSFirm.Activate
```

Comment: We used to get similar issues, and I was able to correct most of them by declaring a driver (Teradata gives me the most grief usually).  I also started avoiding DSNs since I have users who like name their connections something completely different.  Also, a refresh will fail there if there's an access issue.

Comment: This may or may not help, but I notice that strConn = "ODBC;DSN=KundeDB;" & strLoginData appears before strLoginData has been assigned a value.  It doesn't look like the connection string contains the login credentials.  Just my two cents!

Comment: You're right...  I corrected it but I still get the general odbc error in the .refresh line.... :(

Answer (score 6):

I can't solve your problem, but I can help you debug it.

The first question is: what does that error message mean? Is it telling you that there's an error with the query or command you're running on the data, or is something preventing you connecting to the database?

It is actually possible to write informative error messages, and whatever misguided genius at Redmond implemented the Query Table **chose** not to pass through the detailed error information emitted by the database server and the connection libraries.

Fortunately, we do some of that work ourselves.

The QueryTable object has a connection property - it's a string, not a fully-featured connection object, but you can  examine it in more detail and test it against the ADODB connection object. Try this function for testing connection strings, and see if there's any useful information:

```
Public Sub ConnectionTest(ConnectionString As String)

' Late-binding: requires less effort, but he correct aproach is
' to create a reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects' -

'Dim conADO As ADODB.Connection
'Set conADO = New ADODB.Connection
Dim conADO As Object
Set conADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim i As Integer

conADO.ConnectionTimeout = 30
conADO.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

On Error Resume Next

conADO.Open

If conADO.State = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Connection string is valid"
Else
    Debug.Print "Connection failed:"


    For i = 0 To conADO.Errors.Count
        With conADO.Errors(i)
            Debug.Print "ADODB connection returned error " & .Number & " (native error '" & .NativeError & "') from '" & .Source & "': " & .Description
        End With
    Next i


End If

Debug.Print "Connection String: "
Debug.Print vbTab & Replace(.Connection, ";", ";" & vbCrLf & vbTab)
Debug.Print


Set conADO = Nothing


End Sub
```

...And insert it into your code:

```
Dim objQueryTable As Excel.QueryTable
Dim strConnect as String

set objQueryTable = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstringFirma)
 
    With objQueryTable 
        strConnect = .Connection
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh '  "General ODBC error" hereeee
    End With
 
ConnectionTest strConnect  ' view the output in the debug window/immediate pane
```

If you can see errors in that, it might just be that my implementation of an ADODB connection doesn't work in your Mac Office environment: but it's entirely possible that you have either:

1. Created a connection, seen it working, and eliminated the
   possibility that your connection string or DSN is the source of the
   problem...
2. ...Or spotted an error in the connection parameters which you can
   fix.

If the connection's working, it's probably the query or command you're running at the database that's the source of the problem - and the error messages I've seen in your question do point in that direction - so we need to delve a little deeper.

Unfortunately, I have no way of knowing whether the tools I use for that will work for you: this is developers' debugging code, and you'll need to tinker with it to get it to work.

The reason it's so fiddly is that the Office team who implemented the QueryTable made some interesting decisions: the 'connection' and 'recordset' properties exposed by the QueryTable aren't fully-featured objects - I think that they are interfaces which allow the QueryTable to make use of objects *called*  'connection' and 'recordset'  from a variety of different providers, and expose a common set of properties and methods. It's a good decision for cross-platform  usability, but it means that a developer who needs to interrogate those objects can't rely on any given method being present at runtime - **so this is for decompiled code in 'debug' mode only.**

You'll also need to register Microsoft DAO and ADO references in the IDE: late-binding with 'CreateObject' is the wrong tool when you need to be able to view these objects in the 'Locals' window:

```
Public Sub ConnectionDetails(objQueryTable As Excel.QueryTable)

Dim rstADO As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conADO As ADODB.Connection

Dim rstDAO As DAO.Recordset
Dim conDAO As DAO.Connection

Dim i As Integer


Set objQueryTable = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).QueryTable

With objQueryTable


    Debug.Print "Connection String: "
    Debug.Print vbTab & Replace(.Connection, ";", ";" & vbCrLf & vbTab)
    Debug.Print


    Debug.Print "Query Type: " & .QueryType  ' Documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835313.aspx
    Debug.Print "Query: " & .CommandText
    Debug.Print "Database request type: " & .CommandType   ' XlCmdType documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197456.aspx


    .MaintainConnection = True

    On Error Resume Next
    If TypeOf .Recordset Is DAO.Recordset Then


        On Error Resume Next
        Set rstDAO = .Recordset


        rstDAO.OpenRecordset
        For i = 0 To DAO.Errors.Count
            With DAO.Errors(i)
                Debug.Print "DAO Recordset '" & Left(rstDAO.Name, 24) & "' returned error " & .Number & " from '" & .Source & "': " & .Description
            End With
        Next i


        Set conADO = DAO.DBEngine.OpenConnection(.Connection)
        For i = 0 To DAO.Errors.Count
            With DAO.Errors(i)
                Debug.Print "DAO Connection '" & Left(conDAO.Name, 24) & "' returned error " & .Number & " from '" & .Source & "': " & .Description
            End With
        Next i


    ElseIf TypeOf .Recordset Is ADODB.Recordset Then


        On Error Resume Next
        Set rstADO = .Recordset


        If rstADO.State <> 0 Then rstADO.Close
        rstADO.Open
        Set conADO = rstADO.ActiveConnection
        For i = 0 To conADO.Errors.Count
            With conADO.Errors(i)
                Debug.Print "ADODB Recordset '" & Left(rstADO.Source, 24) & "' connection returned error " & .Number & " (native error '" & .NativeError & "') from '" & .Source & "': " & .Description
            End With
        Next i

    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then


        Debug.Print Err.Source & " Error " & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description


    Else


        Debug.Print "recordset type is: '" & TypeName(.Recordset) & "': for further information, place a breakpoint in the code and use the 'Locals' window."


    End If

End With

End Sub
```

What the code does - or attempts to do - is quite straightforward: it interrogates the database and retrieves the detailed error messages.

They will probably tell you that there's a syntax error, or a missing parameter in the SQL - which can be misleading if the database is MS-Access: 'missing parameter' might mean a field name or function name is unknown. It might also mean that [you can't run that SQL outside an MS-Access user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226635/vba-function-in-excel-adodb-query/26738852#26738852).

If it fails to work, go back to the ConnectionTest code and run the command text against the conADO connection object:
`conADO.Execute strCommandText`
...And interrogate the errors collection again.

That's pretty much it for the debugging tools I can bring to bear on this problem: hopefully another 'Stacker can suggest other approaches.

Comment: Before I'll test your codes, some more information: No ADODB is not supported. If you follow the link "Here" in my original post then you can see what I have already tried before this code seemed to work. I already found out that there are a lot of problems regarding connections to databases in which the command .Refresh fails but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem which also works with me. What I do not understand is, that THIS CODE WORKED BEFORE. I put in a line of code (and even after deleting it) it stated the error "General ODBC error" on the .refresh command line.

Comment: Also the commands .Recordset as well as ODBC.Connection aren't known to excel 2011 on mac (at least I get an error message saying so...). Could there be a problem with my object-libraries?

Comment: By the way: Many many thanks for helping me... Sadly, the first code you wrote throws an active-x error because of adodb... I will exchange it for odbc and try again

Comment: Try the `ConnectionTest()` code sample anyway: ADODB might not be supported by the QueryTable object, but the ADO libraries *might* be implemented on the Mac - which means that you can use ADODB to test the connection, and maybe even run the query...

Comment: ...If ADODB doesn't work at all on the Mac, your next route is the Excel 'Data' menu: click 'Connections' and create a connection from scratch using the DSN file. You should see a 'test connection' function somewhere in the dialogue, so you can at least rule out one source of errors. I strongly recommend that you build the query on the table, as a table rather than a 'SELECT' query, as that makes better use of indexes, and allows you to rule out an error in the SQL parsing layer. ...As for why it stopped working, I take a fatalistic approach: another patch, another lockdown, must be Tuesday.

Comment: If I manually connect the workbook with the database and write the query exactly the same, it works without errors. Problem is that if I wanted to record a macro doing it, most part is missing, when re-running that macro it will never work... (tested several times)

Comment: another bit of information: I have debug-printed the amount of query tables after the first QueryTables.Add and the querytable gets created, so the problem is most likely linked to the .refresh command. If anyone would know a workaround for the .Refresh commands I will be happy to try anything....

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error introduced by the macro recorder - although I wouldn't expect a 'general ODBC error' to come back from that. Taking that error at face value, there's a persistent item in memory that's preventing the 'requery. So your next step will be: 1: explicitly dismiss the objects with `Set objQueryTable = Nothing`, and put `.SaveData = False` and a `.MaintainConnection = False` (or True!) in your code. 
You might also want to try `.CancelRefresh`, although I think it's likely to raise an error.

Comment: Is .MaintainConnection a Method of the QueryTable? If yes, it doesn't exist on Mac. I'm trying with the other tipps now... CancelRefresh also doesn't work for my QT. And even with the .SaveData = False I still get the general odbc error in the .refresh line... So, no luck this time either... :(

Comment: @Kathara - yes, MaintainConnection a QueryTable method - I'm surprised it's missing. 'SaveData' is about cacheing data locally so that the query table can support reversible sort, filter and drill-down without requerying the remote data - but it won't save you from an odbc error when you actually query (or requery) the remote data. Meanwhile how did you get on with debugging? - I think your most pressing requirement is to get the database to give you a detailed error message that tells you exactly where the error is and what it is.

Comment: so I would have to take out the refresh command? Just for you to know ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll throws the same error if I put it before the Call... (see EDIT)

Comment: I believe I may have just found the problem. Will comment as soon as I have fixed the issue...

Comment: No, the refresh command is essential - it's the place where the error occurs (or where the error report becomes visible)  - unless you've managed to go deeper into the code and get debugging information out of a connection command or an actual retrieval.