# How to access SQLite database on Mac as ADO not working on Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sqlite, odbc

I have installed Actual ODBC driver for Mac and can access SQLite database through a DSN now, but **I want to access a SQLite database through VBA code**. Is it anyway to do this in Mac.

I have access SQLite database in Windows by Ado. But it seems the ActiveX is only not working in Mac.

Comment: Please define "not working".  Are you getting an error? What have you tried?  I think it's safe to assume that ActiveX needs to be working for Active Data Objects to work -- but I can't guarantee since your question doesn't include as much information as it could.

Comment: ADO is not supported on Mac, simplest option is an ODBC driver & a QueryTable E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433645/vba-code-to-fetch-data-from-mysql-db-in-mac-excel-2011

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give many details. I try my best to explain it. The main point is that I want to change an SQLite database, which will be chosen by the user in Mac excel. So I can get the name and address of the database. Then I can present the information in the database into an Excel sheet. Is it anyway to do this?